# toString on a negative number doesn't compile in Scala Worksheet

Tags: scala, scala-ide

If I create a Scala Worksheet in Eclipse as follows:

```
object negative {

  2.toString                                //> res0: String = 2

  (2).toString                              //> res1: String = 2

  // compile error
  (-2).toString
}
```

the final line causes a compile error:

> ';' expected but ')' found. illegal start of simple expression

However, the same three lines compile and run fine within a normal Scala source file.

Why does this not work in the worksheet?

This is using Eclipse 3.7.2, Scala IDE 3.0.0.v-2_10, Scala Worksheet 0.1.4.v-2_10

*[Updated: this question originally used toBinaryString, but the problem occurs even with toString, so I have simplified it]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. The code in the main object (the first one) of a worksheet is instrumented before being executed. In the 2 mentioned case, the result of the instrumentation is not valid Scala code.

But it is only a problem if the code is at the top level in the main object. If the code is moved to a function or a different object in the same file, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I have reported it as a bug [here](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/issues/160)

Comment: It also works if you just wrap it in a code block {} within the main object.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse worksheets are quite beta; for example last I checked, it couldn't handle a `@tailrec` decoration on a function.

So this is most probably a bug or limitation in Eclipse. After all, the feature seems quite new, and there are many other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

`(-2).toBinaryString`
gives same error for me.

Note that `java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString(-2)`works just fine.