# Scala, calling a list and simple test of the code

Tags: scala

This  is a code for sum function ( that need to be checked)

```
object Lists { 

 def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = 

    [some scala code]

}
```

How is it possible to check it with a list? how  is it usually done simply, and how to write simple assert on this?

Comment: You seem to be doing the Coursera course [_Functional Programming in Scala_](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun). This is the example assignment to introduce you to the process of doing future assignments. There is a video available to guide you through the process, including testing your code with the interactive sbt console. You have also downloaded a very well-documented example test suite that contains some basic checks on your sum function and will guide you through the process of writing additional test cases.

Comment: thanks Carsten ,i am i still get very confused with syntax hopefully with time it will be smoother. thanks i'll check it again

Comment: I think it's a great question personally there is not such a thing as bad question. Enlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is a built-in sum function in scala:

```
> List(1,2,3,4).sum
res0: Int = 10
```

So you can assume that it works just fine and assert your function against it. Next, I would test your code through the corner cases.

- What if list is empty?
- What if it contains all zeroes?
- What if it contains negative numbers?

and so on

```
object Lists { 
 // I'm writing checks inline, but commonly we write them in separate file 
 // as scalatest or specs test
 // moreover, require, which is build in scala function, is mostly used for checking of input
 // but I use it there for simplicity 
 private val Empty = List.empty[Int]
 private val Negatives = List(-1, 1, -2, 2, 3)
 private val TenZeroes = List.fill(10)(0)
 require(sum(Empty)     == Empty.sum)
 require(sum(Negatives)  == Negatives.sum)
 require(sum(TenZeroes) == 0)
 // etc

 def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = 
    if(xs.isEmpty) 0
    else xs.head + sum(xs.tail)
}
```

There is a tool in scala that may ease generation of test data like this: [scalacheck](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck). It will feed your functions with all kinds of input: large and negative numbers, zeroes, nulls, empty strings, empty lists, large lists -- everything that average developer forgets to check. It isn't easy for novices, but definitely worth looking.

Comment: this worked perfect in the "Scala Worksheet" I was trying to run it real time in the .scala and didn't understand the difference.

Comment: Well, worksheet is usually used to play with existing code or prototype new one -- in large amounts of code we cannot and we shouldn't load everything into it. Worksheet [is still buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18961790/298389). Or you're asking about something else?

Answer (score 2):

to check your method invoke it in a main method:

```
object Lists {

  def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int =
    if(xs.isEmpty) 0
    else xs.head + sum(xs.tail)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(sum(List(1,2,3)))
  }
}
```

Another way to invoke the sum operation on a list you can do:

```
List(1,2,3).sum
```